# Relativpronomen beim Genitiv

Tags: declension

> Eine Mutter, deren Kind weinte, war auch sehr beunruhigt

Ich habe diesen Satz bei einer Grammatikübung gefunden. Es sollte doch *dessen*, statt *deren* heissen?

Comment: Nein, sollte es nicht. Warum glaubst du, dass es so sein sollte?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der Satz ist so richtig, wie er da steht. Das possessive Relativpronomen ist abhängig vom Bezugswort:

- maskulines Bezugswort: dessen
- feminines Bezugswort: deren
- neutrales Bezugswort: dessen
- Bezugswort im Plural: deren

Somit:

> Eine Mutter, deren Kind weinte, ...
>    Ein Vater, dessen Kind weinte, ...

Comment: Man könnte vielleicht noch klarstellen, dass es sich nicht um ein Pronomen handelt, sondern um einen relativen Begleiter. [Wie alle Begleiter bezieht es sich auch auf das begleitete Nomen, wird aber nicht nach ihm dekliniert, sondern ist invariabel. Das jeweilige 'Bezugswort' steht im Obersatz, was aber nicht eigens erwähnt zu werden braucht. Dennoch ist diese Doppelbezüglichkeit verwirrend - sie ist sogar dreifach, denn die syntaktische Funktion innerhalb des Relativsatzes ist auch noch zu berücksichtigen, nur hier nicht, wegen der Unveränderlichkeit.]